# skipping step x to step y and validate step x data

Tags: django, django-formwizard

I have actually a big problem on a django wizard form.

I have 3 steps. The second step can contains data or not. The last step is a file upload step.

In the WizardForm class, i overrided the get_context_data method and include this in it :

```
if self.steps.current == 'against_indication':
        questions = None
        try:
            # get the machine
            machine_id = self.kwargs['pk']
            machine = Machine.objects.get(pk=int(machine_id))
            # check if there is against indications
            if machine.type_question is False:
                questions = YhappsQuestion.objects.filter(type_modalite=machine.type)
            else:
                questions = CustomQuestion.objects.filter(machine=machine)
        except Machine.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        if len(questions) == 0:
            # we modify the form wizard to skip against indication step
            self.render_next_step(form, **kwargs)
            #self.render_goto_step(step='against_indication', goto_step='prescription', **kwargs)
```

As you see, if there is no questions, i skip the second step (against_indication) to go into the next step (prescription).

The problem appears here. When the last step is rendered, there is not enough data in the wizard form. In the ddt's request there is it :
[with skip step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2wE4.png).
So if i upload the file, it gonna fill the against_indication datas instead of prescription datas, and re-renderer me the last step...

I tried to do all of this without skip the second step, and see how look the ddt's request :
[without skip step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VD1ci.png).

Someone has a solution to permit have the right datas when i skip step, plz ?

Thanks for your further answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think `get_context_data` is the correct method to do this in; FormWizard is a very specific class that restricts where you can perform different functions.

The typical way to specify when `FormWizard` skips a step is to use a `condition_dictionary`. Django uses the structure to only include the form for a step when the conditions (set as callables) return `True`. If not, then that step's form doesn't force `form.is_valid()` to be called, bypassing the validation of that step. This also assures that all hidden management info for the form is created for each step.

Here's a example of how this can work:

```
# I always specify index values for steps so that all functions can share them
STEP_ONE = u'0'
STEP_TWO = u'1'
STEP_THREE = u'2'


def YourFormWizard(SessionWizardView):
    # Your form wizard itself; will not be called directly by urls.py, but rather wrapped in a function that provide the condition_dictionary
    _condition_dict = { # a dictionary with key=step, value=callable function that return True to show step and False to not
        STEP_ONE: return_true, # callable function that says to always show this step
        STEP_TWO: check_step_two, # conditional callable for verifying whether to show step two
        STEP_THREE: return_true, # callable function that says to always show this step
    }
    _form_list = [ # a list of forms used per step
        (STEP_ONE,your_forms.StepOneForm),
        (STEP_TWO, your_forms.StepTwoForm),
        (STEP_THREE, your_forms.StepThreeForm),
    ]
    ...


def return_true(wizard): #  callable function called in _condition_dict
    return True # a condition that is always True, for when you always want form seen

def check_step_two(wizard): #  callable function called in _condition_dict
    step_1_info = wizard.get_cleaned_data_for_step(STEP_ONE)
    # do something with info; can retrieve for any prior steps
    if step_1_info == some_condition:
        return True # show step 2
    else: return False # or don't

''' urls.py '''

your_form_wizard = YourFormWizard.as_view(YourFormWizard._form_list,condition_dict= YourFormWizard._condition_dict)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^form_wizard_url/$', your_form_wizard, name='my-form-wizard',) 
)
```

Comment: Thanks @IanPrice ! This exemple of using condition_dict is really more understable than the official django exemple. It saved my day :)

Comment: Great to hear! Yeah, the docs are really not very good for FW.

Comment: And if I was able to help, marking this as an answer and upvoting is appreciated :)

Comment: @IanPrice Thanks for your great answer. I tried to improve it in another answer. Please let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on great Ian Price answer, I tried to make some improvements because I noticed structure could help over time, especially if you try to change order of your steps:

- I used a dataclass to centralize data about a step wizard, then generating required data for urls later.
- I used lambdas for returning True and giving callable is optional
- I extracted STEP_X in a const.py files to be re-usable
- I tried as possible to gather data within the class view itself rather than in functions

Here is the code (Python 3.7+):

#### const.py

```
STEP_0 = '0'
STEP_1 = '1'
STEP_2 = '2'
```

#### views.py

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional, Callable, Sequence


@dataclass
class WizardStepData:
    step: str
    form_class: any
    trigger_condition: Optional[Callable] = None

    def __init__(self, step, form_class, trigger_condition=None):
        """ if trigger_condition is not provided, we return a Callable that returns True """
        self.step = step
        self.form_class = form_class
        self.trigger_condition = trigger_condition if trigger_condition else lambda _: True


def YourFormWizard(SessionWizardView):
    @staticmethod
    def check_step_one(wizard) -> bool:
        pass  # ...

    @classmethod
    def get_wizard_data_list(cls) -> Sequence:
        return [
            WizardStepData(step=STEP_0,
                           form_class=StepZeroForm),
            WizardStepData(step=STEP_1,
                           form_class=StepOneForm,
                           trigger_condition=cls.check_step_one),
            WizardStepData(step=STEP_2,
                           form_class=StepTwoForm),
        ]

    @classmethod
    def _condition_dict(cls) -> dict:
        return {data.step: data.trigger_condition for data in cls.get_wizard_data_list()}

    @classmethod
    def _form_list(cls) -> list:
        return [(data.step, data.form_class) for data in cls.get_wizard_data_list()]
```

#### urls.py

```
# ...
your_form_wizard = YourFormWizard.as_view(form_list=YourFormWizard._form_list(),
                                          condition_dict=YourFormWizard._condition_dict())
```